# Rex command not found

Tags: macos, perl, macports, cpan, rex

I am trying to install Rex on Mac OS X (El Capitan), following the instructions at https://www.rexify.org/get.html

I have installed XCode and MacPorts.

Below are the responses I got from the installation commands now

```
$ sudo port install libssh2 perl5
--->  Computing dependencies for libssh2
--->  Cleaning libssh2
--->  Computing dependencies for perl5
--->  Cleaning perl5
--->  Scanning binaries for linking errors
--->  No broken files found.

$ curl -L https://get.rexify.org | perl - --sudo -n Rex
% Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                             Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
100  294k  100  294k    0     0    99k      0  0:00:02  0:00:02 --:--:--   99k
Rex is up to date. (1.3.3)
```

Although the install scripts told me it's up to date, I cannot run the command:

```
$ rex
-bash: rex: command not found
```

I have tried on another Mac OS X machine and there was no problems. Could someone help me to fix this weird situation?

***Update:***

Doing a `$ find / -name rex`, I found one instance in `/opt/local/libexec/perl5.22/sitebin/`. Did the installer make some mistakes when creating the bin folder?

Comment: Check your path on both.

Comment: What path do you mean? On the working machine, rex can be found in /usr/local/bin/. But not on the one I got problems. I could not find any ways to uninstall / reinstall yet.

Comment: Clearly `Rex` has been installed somewhere other than you were expecting. But that installer you've just run - makes my head hurt. I would suggest that you check `perl -v` and which perl version and install locations it's using. But otherwise - there's really insufficient detail here to solve the problem.

Answer (score 2):

You need to find out where the perl modules are installed on your system using

```
perl -e 'print join "\n", @INC;'
```

You will find `rex` in one of the perl module directories in the subdirectory "bin".

Try this:

```
for PERLINC in $(perl -e 'print join "\n", @INC;') 
do ls -l $PERLINC/Rex-1.3.3/bin/rex; done
```